# user defined custom aggregate function using plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a problem.The tool i work on does not accept subqueries. So i have to write a user defined custom aggregate function that does the following.

Example: col1 and col2 has numeric datatype.

```
**col1**    **col2**
243         401
57489       400
2789        401
598         400

SELECT sum(MinValue) 
FROM
    (SELECT Min(col1) AS MinValue,col2
    FROM
    Table1
    GROUP BY col2)

Output:841
```

I want this query to work in a single step by using a single function rather than as the query shown above. Something like:

```
SELECT MyMinSum(col1, col2),col3 from table1 Group by col3;
```

I hope it makes sense. I will appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for same output what you are getting with your select statement using sub query, you could achieve the same result by

```
         SELECT   SUM (MIN (col1)) AS minvalue
 FROM   Table1
GROUP BY   col2
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to put your SQL in a view, assuming that works with your tool.

But if you really need a custom aggregate function, there are two main ways to do it.  The typical way is to use [Oracle Data Cartridge Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/aggr_functions.htm#CECJAAJG), such as the popular [STRAGG](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402).  But in my experience, Data Cartridge is confusing, full of bugs, and slow.  Usually the `COLLECT` function works much better.  See the example below, or this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/acb68/4).

```
create table table1(col1 number, col2 number, col3 number)
/

insert into table1
select 243,   401, 1 from dual union all
select 57489, 400, 1 from dual union all
select 2789,  401, 1 from dual union all
select 598,   400, 1 from dual union all
select 598,   400, 2 from dual
/

create or replace type col1_col2_obj is object
(
  col1 number,
  col2 number
)
/

create or replace type col1_col2_nt is table of col1_col2_obj
/

create or replace function MyMinSum(p_col1_col2_nt in col1_col2_nt)
return number is
  v_result number;
begin
  SELECT sum(MinValue)
  INTO v_result
  FROM
  (
    SELECT Min(col1) AS MinValue,col2
    FROM
    table(p_col1_col2_nt)
    GROUP BY col2
  );

  return v_result;
end;
/

select
  MyMinSum(cast(collect(col1_col2_obj(col1, col2)) as col1_col2_nt)) test
  ,col3
from table1
group by col3
/


TEST    COL3
841     1
598     2
```